# WearableListView is always null when I changed my wear layout to WatchViewStub from BoxInsetLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os

I have an app that was using BoxInsetLayout but the round layout wasn't working out so I have to change it to WatchViewStub.

I changed to code so that it uses either a round layout or a square layout and that works find. There was a WearableListView inside the original layout file which was just one file. Now it is 3 files, the main one, and the round or square one. Now the listview is always null even though there are no compile time errors.

My onCreate in the main activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_select);

    WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub watchViewStub) {
            mRectangleBackground = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rectLayout);
            mRoundBackground = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.roundLayout);

        }
    });

    WearableListView listView = (WearableListView) findViewById(R.id.list); // this is always null

    listView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    listView.setAdapter(new SportAdapter(this));
    listView.setClickListener(this);
}
```

My view select xml file (the WatchViewStub)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:rectLayout="@layout/view_select_square"
app:roundLayout="@layout/view_select_round"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:id="@+id/stub"
android:background="@color/green_forest">

</android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub>
```

The square layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
app:layout_box="all"
android:id="@+id/rectLayout">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:text="@string/text_select_sport"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="26sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_title"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Whenever I call listView anything like setAdapter, setHasFixedSize, I get a null reference error. Why is my listView always null?

Here is the xml file when it was BoxInsetLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:background="@color/green_forest">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_box="all">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text_title"
        android:text="@string/text_select_sport"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_title">

        <android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

and the main activity before any changes

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_select);
    WearableListView listView = (WearableListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    listView.setAdapter(new SportAdapter(this));
    listView.setClickListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it by adding another method loadAdapter like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_select);


    WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub watchViewStub) {
            mRectangleBackground = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rectLayout);
            mRoundBackground = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.roundLayout);
            listView = (WearableListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            loadAdapter();
        }
    });

}

private void loadAdapter() {
    listView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    listView.setAdapter(new SportAdapter(this));
    listView.setClickListener(this);
}
```

as seen in this example here https://gist.github.com/PomepuyN/c30760eaee1e58fdd8fa

ugh...

Comment: Out of curiousity, why did you want to switch from BoxInsetLayout?

Comment: @dazza5000 because the layout which worked in the square watch app didn't translate well to the round watch